# How to create a Unity Editor box grouping with a header and vertically stacked content inside?

Tags: unity, gui

I am trying to do something like this with Unity Editor for my window but I am not sure how it is done.

[image]

So it is basically a box ( a wrapper ) with a title at top. Beneath the title there are boxes or "cards" where you add text to it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is too broad. Try to explain what you want to achieve more detailed.

Comment: I want to make this ui

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this is for an Editor window (ie. a control you're using to help build your game in the Unity editing software, not something that's rendered in the game itself for the player to interact with)?

Comment: Yes @DMGregory you are right

Answer (score 2):

Just use `GUILayout.BeginVertical` with style `window`.

```cs
GUILayout.BeginVertical("Card Title", "window");
GUILayout.Button("button 1");
GUILayout.Button("button 2");
GUILayout.Label("some text");
GUILayout.Label("more text");
GUILayout.Label("still text");
GUILayout.EndVertical();
```

Result:
[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

To comment from @zwcloud
If you want that GUILayout.BeginVertical("Card Title", "window"); not to fill all the free area to the bottom of editor you can add this line after GUILayout.EndVertical() :
**GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();**